# Stripe failed payment card details

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to check the failed payment response from Stripe. Is there any Stripe test card details which will create the subscription but failed to pay?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have the first payment succeed on a subscription, as far as I know with a test card, so you would need to use this card (4000000000000341) that can be attached to a customer record without performing an authorization and then create your subscription with a trial period (even a trial period of ~30 seconds into the future).